# Is there something similar to "SELECT FOR UPDATE" in MongoDB and Netezza as like SQL?

Tags: sql, mongodb, netezza

I want similar command or query for "SELECT FOR UPDATE" as like SQL in MongoDB and Netezza. In SQL we do it using BEGIN and COMMIT.

I am trying to perform a operation which locks particular document or record in MongoDB and Netezza, while trying modification in same document we should not be able to do that.

In PostgreSQL we do that with -

```sql
    Begin;
    SELECT * FROM pollcheck
    WHERE status != 'processed' or status=null FOR UPDATE

    UPDATE pollcheck SET status = 'inserted' where recordid=3
    commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [findAndModify](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/):

```
db.collection.findAndModify({
    query: <document>,
    sort: <document>,
    remove: <boolean>,
    update: <document or aggregation pipeline>, // Changed in MongoDB 4.2
    new: <boolean>,
    fields: <document>,
    upsert: <boolean>,
    bypassDocumentValidation: <boolean>,
    writeConcern: <document>,
    collation: <document>,
    arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ],
    let: <document> // Added in MongoDB 5.0
});
```

Comment: Can you please demonstrate with an example ? exactly how it works, so I can understand in a better way. @gotqn